# pandoc: How to set geometry driver

Tags: ubuntu, geometry, debian, driver, pandoc

I have pandoc installed in **Debian 10** and in **Ubuntu 20.04**. When I run pandoc it uses different geometry drivers.

```
# Debian 10
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex

# Ubuntu 20.04
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
```

Is there a way to force pandoc to use **pdftex** as the geometry driver? It seems **xetex** is causing me some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem this can be done using the -V parameter as such:

```
pandoc -V geometry:driver=pdftex -s test.md -o test.pdf
```